# Java/JAXB error in Matlab when using unmarshal function

Tags: java, matlab, jaxb

I'm running into a problem that I think is related to updating JAXB to the latest version.  I'm running a marshal command that returns:

```
Java exception occurred:
javax.xml.bind.MarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.String; cannot be cast to java.lang.String]
        at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.write(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.marshal(Unknown Source)
        at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractMarshallerImpl.marshal(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.String; cannot be cast to java.lang.String
        at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.reportError(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.reportError(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.AdaptedLister$ListIteratorImpl.next(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayElementProperty.serializeListBody(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayERProperty.serializeBody(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeBody(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsXsiType(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.property.SingleElementNodeProperty.serializeBody(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeBody(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsSoleContent(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeRoot(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsRoot(Unknown Source)
        ... 3 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.String; cannot be cast to java.lang.String
        at javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.NormalizedStringAdapter.marshal(Unknown Source)
        ... 13 more
```

This code used to work with Jaxb1, but now returns this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It used to work with the same input? The error is telling you that the marshaller is for some reason trying to cast a string array to a single string ("[L" = array).